# How do I use comparable method with if conditions when the two types of data are different?

Tags: java, compareto

I have to write an Employee class that has a comparable method that will be used to sort an ArrayList of employees. First it compares the number of years the employee has been working with another employee number of years, if the number of years are the same then it moves on to comparing salary, both conditions should sort in ascending order. My issue is I get an incompatible type error since salary is a double data type, is there anything I can do?

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>
{
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private int years;
    private double salary;

    public Employee(String lastName, String firstName, int years, double salary)
    {
        this.lastName=lastName;
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.years=years;
        this.salary=salary;
    }

    public void setLastName(String newlastName)
    {
        lastName=newlastName;
    }
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }


    public void setFirstName(String newfirstName)
    {
        firstName=newfirstName;
    }
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }


    public void setYears(int newyears)
    {
        years=newyears;
    }
    public int getYears()
    {
        return years;
    }


    public void setSalary(double newsalary)
    {
        salary=newsalary;
    }
    public double getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String s=""+lastName+"-"+firstName+":"+years+":"+salary;
        return s;
    }

    public int compareTo(Employee that)
    {
        if(this.years != that.getYears())
        {
            return this.years - that.getYears();
        }
        else
        {
            return this.salary - that.getSalary();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick fix: Cast the result to an `int` (e.g., `(int) (this.salary - that.salary)`). Note your implementation is vulnerable to a potential numerical underflow, though the years or salaries of your employees would have to be ludicrously large for that to happen. But still, it would be better to do actual comparisons or even use the `Integer#compare(int,int)` and `Double#compare(double,double)` methods. Another approach is to use the fluent API of `Comparator` to create a private static final comparator instance and then just have your `compareTo` implementation delegate to the comparator.

Answer (score 2):

`this.salary - that.getSalary()` results in a `double`, but the `compareTo()` function needs to return an `int`. In general, Java doesn't like to implicitly convert a `double` to an `int` because that results in a loss of information (I presume the error said something about a "lossy conversion").

One way to implement a `compareTo()` that uses `double` variables to compare two objects is to manually return -1, 0, or 1 depending on the comparison:

```
if (this.salary < that.getSalary())
    return -1;
else if (this.salary > that.getSalary())
    return 1;
return 0;
```

Comment: Note code can be simplified to `return Double.compare(this.salary, that.salary);`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like your implementation of `compareTo`.

I would implement `equals` and `hashCode` properly.

If you must implement `Comparable`, it should be consistent with `equals`.

I would not have the `Employee` class implement `Comparable`.  You can do that salary/age comparison with a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no way to allow the `compareTo` method to return something other than an `int`. Luckily, there is a workaround!

Comparables do not need to return the exact difference between the two inputs, just an indication as to which one is larger.

i.e. you don't need to return anything other than `1`, `0`, and `-1`.

Therefore, `Math.signum()` can come to the rescue!

`Math.signum(double d)` returns the sign of `d`, or 0 if `d == 0`.

More info on `Math.signum()` at geeksforgeeks: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-signum-method-examples/

There is a version of signum for integers as well: `Integer.signum(int i)`

It would look something like this in your code:

```java
public int compareTo(Employee that)
{
    if(this.years != that.getYears())
    {
        return Integer.signum(this.years - that.getYears());
    }
    else
    {
        return (int) Math.signum(this.salary - that.getSalary());
    }
}
```

Note that we must cast `Math.signum(this.salary - that.getSalary())` to an `int` because it returns a `double`

Comment: Using `signum` here seems unnecessarily complicated. It adds nothing to the `years` comparison, and you might as well just cast the result of the subtraction for the `salary` comparison to an `int` at that point (see [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72581357/how-do-i-use-comparable-method-with-if-conditions-when-the-two-types-of-data-are#comment128212589_72581357)). And the code is still _theoretically_ vulnerable to numerical underflow.